# CPU speeds don't make any sense

Tags: cpu, processor

I don't understand.... I bought a newer laptop with an i5-3317U core but it's only 1.70Ghz, while my way older laptop that has a i5-M560 core yet is 2.67Ghz. So, since the newer laptop should have a more updated core, why is the specs so much lower?

Comment: I'm sorry but this question is off-topic. In general, different CPUs are targetted for different uses: a lower frequency implies less power demand. Further frequency stopped being relevant since Pentium 4, a newer core has a better-designed microarchitecture that leads to the same performance with lower frequency. Always confront benchmarks, not frequencies. Also, mind the Turbo Boost technology.

Comment: Clock speeds cannot be compared across different *generations* (architectures) of chips. For example, your new i5-3317U processor is an Ivy Bridge, and you can compare GHz ratings on one Ivy Bridge processor to another (faster is better, of course). However, you cannot compare GHz ratings on Ivy Bridge processors to GHz ratings on Haswell processors, or any other non-Ivy Bridge processor. The newer processor will be faster, even though it is running at a slower clock speed. This is due to improvements in the architecture that make the processor more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clock speed only refers to the frequency of instructions executed per unit time . But some CPUs can handle more complex instructions which may be equivalent to several basic instructions in the case of previous gen CPUs . Architecture also matters , hence an efficient Architecture may increase the work done per unit time , irrespective of the clock speed . So in order for a cpu to be a beast , it should have a good efficient architecture and good clock speed .

Plus in some cases lower clock speeds in some modern CPUs are also because they want it to be more energy efficient while being powerful enough to take any load which is well within its limit .

Useful link : https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqnvjPmsLUAhUHuY8KHc9NCM8QFgguMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.howtogeek.com%2F177790%2Fwhy-you-cant-use-cpu-clock-speed-to-compare-computer-performance%2F&usg=AFQjCNFi51BljRrxkt3ZpKlHG4bSQa8L0A